# Accessing and scraping a web page of Comma-Delimited UTF-8 text in Google Apps Script custom function

Tags: javascript, utf-8, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a custom function for google sheets that will access historical weather data from **weather underground** and return the temperature. The data is in a web page that is all comma-delimited UTF-8 text. The first item in each line is the time and the second is the temperature. The function will take input in the form of date-DD, month-MM, year-YYYY, time-HH:MM AM(or PM). I need to go to the web page, find the line with the same hour as the input (all data is taken on the 53rd minute of the hour), and return the temperature at that time.

This is my first time with javascript-esque coding and I think I am opening and decoding the web page incorrectly. In google sheets, it says that TEMP is an unknown function. Thanks.

```
function TEMP(day, month, year, time) {
  var newTime = String(time).split("");
  if(String(newTime[6]).localeCompare('A')){
    var newTime1 = newTime[0] + newTime[1] + ":53 AM";
  }
  else if(String(time[6]).localeCompare('P')){
     newTime1 = newTime[0] + newTime[1] + ":53 PM";
  }
  else{
  }  

  try{
  var url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KTVR/" + year +"/" + month + "/" + day + "/DailyHistory.html?format=1";
  }
  catch(err){
    return "weather data not found"
  }

  var opened = decodeURI(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url));

  for each(var line in opened){
    var newLine = String(line).split(',');
    if(newLine[0] == newTime1){
      return newLine[1];
    }
    else{
    }  
  }

  return "sorry something went wrong";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error here is an incorrect assumption about what [`UrlFetchApp.fetch`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)) returns. I recommend reading the documentation carefully. This method returns an object of class [HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response). What one usually wants from this object is `getContentText()` which returns a string containing the source markup of the webpage. You can split it by newlines to obtain an array; this won't happen on its own just by writing `var line in opened`.

And it makes no sense to use `decodeURI` on this object. This function is for decoding strings representing URIs, like

```
decodeURI("https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B");
```

It's about decoding addresses of webpages, not their content.

Also, you put a wrong thing in a try-catch block. There's no error that could be thrown at the string concatenation step. An error may well occur when fetching the data; you may want to look at `muteHttpExceptions` option of the `fetch` method.

And by all means, get rid of empty `else {}` blocks, what are they for?

After making the following changes to the script,

```
var url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KTVR/" + year +"/" + month + "/" + day + "/DailyHistory.html?format=1";
var opened = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().split('\n');
```

I was able to use `=temp(2,3,2016,"12:34 am")` in my spreadsheet; it returned 52.0.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Everything you said makes sense. Now that you talk about it it seems really unpolished. Still, when I replace the code with what you suggested, my google sheet says that temp() is an unknown function. I tried your input even and it didn't work. The cell is blank after hitting enter. I think there is some problem with the connection between my script and the google sheet.  Any suggestions with this?

Comment: Is your function entered and saved in the script attached to the spreadsheet? Have you tried to reproduce the problem with another function, such as `function one(x) {return 1}`?

Comment: Ok so I made a new spreadsheet and copy and pasted my code into a new script editor and it worked. Not sure why but it's all good now! Thank you!